# Set sonar quality profile from teamcity sonar runner

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity, sonar-runner

I am generating sonar report from teamcity sonar runner but I see that **Quality Profile** is set to
**Use 'Sonar way' (XML)** but I want it to be **Stop using sonar way (xml)**.
Can anyone suggest the parameter or setting I need to do.

Note: I can not share the logs or screenshots here because of organization policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used parameter **sonar.Language=cs**. it excluded xml analysis and now I see **Stop using sonar way (xml)**.

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters

> **sonar.language**
>
> Set the language of the source code to analyze. Browse the Plugin
>   Library page to get the list of all available languages. If not set, a
>   multi-language analysis will be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

The way to handle this is to use the UI to assign the project to the profile(s) you want it to use: Project-level **Administration > Quality Profiles**. You'll be presented there with an option to assign a profile for each language available in the instance.

If you simply *must* do this from TeamCity, then use [web services](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/qualityprofiles/projects) to assign the profile. Although once assigned, assignments "stick" so this really is something you should be able to do from the GUI and then just leave alone.